# Paginator - Unknown column 'page' in 'field list'

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have big form to populate database row so I use `fill(Input::all())` to save my record. Everything is ok on the first page but on the other pages I got error:

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'page' in 'field list'
```

I know that is because `?page=2` in my URL. But what can I use something like `Input::all()` only for POST data? I know I can  put field-names in $fillable in my model, but it is not comfortable (too many fields). I can't put `page` to `$guarded` because somebody can put any word in url (not only 'page').

Comment: Fillable is there for this exact reason, use it. You only have to put it in there once, so why not do that and save yourself the trouble? Input::all gets POST and GET vars.

Comment: I know but it is not comfortable to put all fields-name manually  - one by one. I have not only this one form with a lot of data :)... and I hope to do it more quick in the future. Input::all() for only POST data would be very nice feature.

Comment: It's still just as insecure - I can just create an input, guess a field, and I'd be able to insert it into your table whether you'd like it or not if  you did it that way.

Comment: It's intranet app so security is not so  important here. Otherwise I use csrf protection and validate inputs. Do You think that it is still insecure to use Input:all? Is it still possible to hack it?

Comment: Well anyone on the intranet would still be able to. CSRF doesn't do much either, just stops simpler applications from doing it. More complex applications can get around it. How many fields are we talking? 20? 50? 100?

Comment: I was thinking that if I fill only all POST data, any attempt to hack and put field that not exist in database simple give database error. I know, I'm lazy... I always try easiest way :) But if filling manually $fillable by field names is only one secure way to populate forms, I will do it. Thank You for help and explain.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do this

```
public guarded = array('page');
```

This is the opposite of fillable. It just prevents the page attribute being mass assigned.

Or you can use

```
Input::except('page')
```

which will get all input keys except 'page'.